# How do I estimate the derivative of the current position, when I have only values from past to present?

Tags: signal-processing

If I have a discrete real-time signal $x[n]$, with its latest value $x[i]$ and all its past values $x[i-t]$, how can I estimate the derivative at $x[i]$?

Comment: See e.g. finite difference coefficients: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficients#Forward_and_backward_finite_difference

Comment: Thanks, this could be the answer! 
But what is the $O(h²x)$ there?

Comment: "Derivative", in discrete time? What is it?